# Make Changes to Wordpress Graphene Template

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates

I have bee getting to grips with Wordpress and so far so good. The one thing I cant workout is how to edit the default template which is being used for my home page and any subsequent new pages I create.

My aim is to remove the "Comments" and "Latest News" that appear by default and instead setup my own image slider, text etc.

I just cant find the code that is setting what appears in the template.

So far, as well as lots of digging in the files, I have created a new child template and CSS to go with it but now I need some help.

Thanks all.

Comment: use an application like sublime text to search in all the theme files for the code corresponding to the section you want to remove

Comment: seems like you might need to just read up more on what and how wordpress works, what you want to do you will need to know which template file wordpress is rendering and also where to find it, sometimes widgets sometimes template php codes. no one here can help you without looking at the system.

Comment: A lot of different wp themes allow you to edit some of the files directly by going to Dashboard->Appearance->Editor. Usually there are comment divs/spans found in 'post' and 'page' templates, which you can remove here.